# Verification failed csrf

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I tried to write a code in python using requests to login to a website but at the end I got this error: "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." how can fix it?

```
import requests

s = requests.session()

payload = {
    
'email': '***@gmail.com',
'password': '***',
'sign_in_submit': '***'

}

response = s.post("https://www.mongard.ir/accounts/login/", data=payload)
print(response.content)
```

Comment: You missed to send a token that is embedded in the page and has to be retrieved prior to sending data.

Answer (score 0):

**CSRF stands for Cross Site Request Forgery**

The site you are sending the request to has a CSRF token, which is to prevent other sites from sending data to itself for the sake of security, and that means you would not be able to send requests without the CSRF tokens generated on the site.

For example, on a website written with Django, there might be something like this in the html:

```html
<form action=".....">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
</form>
```

Hope I explained it clearly.